# SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery doesn't return correct results using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, android, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have a strange and inexplicable error with my prepared SQL statement, it doesn't deliver the same results as the noprepared statement.

Shouldn't these two versions return the same results?

Prepared version (with wrong results):

```
sb.append(" WHERE c.deck_id=? AND c.next_date < ? AND c.next_date > 0 AND c.active > 0 AND c.deck_level=?");
...
return db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), new String[] { Long.toString(deckId)
, Long.toString(now), Long.toString(level)});
```

Nonprepared version (works as expected with correct results):

```
sb.append(" WHERE c.deck_id=").append(deckId)
.append(" AND c.next_date<").append(now)
.append(" AND c.next_date > 0 AND c.active > 0 AND c.deck_level=").append(level);
...
return db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
```

**Where is the error in the preparted statement version?**

**Update**
I made additional logs for both versions.

```
Log.d(TAG, "selectionArgs1:" + Long.toString(deckId) + ""+Long.toString(now)+ ""+Long.toString(level)+ "");
```

Output: selectionArgs1:*5*1294429481330*5*
(SO: doesn't display * in the source?)

```
StringBuffer d = new StringBuffer("selectionArgs2:");
d.append(deckId).append("").append(now).append("").append(level).append("");
Log.d(TAG, d.toString());
```

Output: selectionArgs2:*5*1294429481330*5*

Comment: output both strings to logcat and compare them.

Comment: @Phyrum Tea: Off the cuff, they should return the same results.

Comment: @sugarynugs: I have set a breakpoint there to copy the sql query and replaced the values manually, copied the database from the emulator, and executed the query with sqlite3. It delivers the correct results. I went through the rawQuery sourcecode up to the native parts, nothing seems to be wrong. When I get home after work, I'll have a new look at the problem.

Comment: I printed both queries to the log and compared both in a texteditor. After replacing the ? chars with the values, they are both the same. I'm using the nonprepared one and may revisit the problem later. At least the other prepared statements in my app seem to work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Phyrum - could you post the schema for the 'c' table?

Comment: I have thought about NULL values that might be effecting but all are not null. CREATE TABLE cards (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,deck_id INTEGER,side_a TEXT,side_b TEXT,side_c TEXT,side_d TEXT,side_a_type INTEGER,side_b_type INTEGER,side_c_type INTEGER,side_d_type INTEGER,side_a_file_id INTEGER,side_b_file_id INTEGER,side_c_file_id INTEGER,side_d_file_id INTEGER,deck_level INTEGER,status INTEGER,flag INTEGER,last_date INTEGER,next_date INTEGER,spacing INTEGER,created INTEGER,modified INTEGER,last_right

Comment: ... INTEGER,last_wrong INTEGER,review_date INTEGER,right_count INTEGER,wrong_count INTEGER,card_order INTEGER,active INTEGER,selected INTEGER); -- too long.

Comment: Does Long.toString(deckId) equate to sb.append(deckId) etc? For each query to give different output, the query strings must be different somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its something to do with [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) but I've not been able to reproduce the issue *exactly* as you describe.

Affinity behaviour can affect comparison expressions, so the 'unprepared'

```
next_date < 12345678
```

might not be not equivalent to the 'prepared':

```
next_date < '12345678'
```

Note the implied string data type applied by 'rawQuery' binding - the [`rawQuery`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) javadoc says:

> The values will be bound as Strings.

I tried to cook up a test case with a `next_date INTEGER` field to no avail.  But, if the field is left untyped, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE cards ( next_date );

INSERT INTO cards SELECT 1234;
INSERT INTO cards SELECT '1234';

SELECT 'int', typeof( next_date ), next_date FROM cards WHERE next_date < 1234;
SELECT 'str', typeof( next_date ), next_date FROM cards WHERE next_date < '1234';
```

Then the different affinity behaviour can be seen - the result is:

```
str|integer|1234
```

*(Perhaps this is a comment, but it's easier to read formatted as an answer.)*

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])*

Comment: I suspect in a similar direction, rawQuery only binds to strings and I have integers. That means, that I cannot trust prepared statements with integers?

Comment: I accept your hint, after looking at http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html it's certainly a problem using prepared statement if you have non strings involved in a comparison. See part "3.4 Comparison Example"

Comment: But that doesn't fully explain the behavior because integer is in the first rule.

Comment: @Phyrum - I agree, it's not a complete answer by any means.  Might be worth trying "next_date < CAST( ? AS INTEGER )" to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: That CAST did it! Thanks a lot!